# What is the definition of the "bias corrected and accelerated" bootstrap confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, definition

Googling shows several references, but all locked up.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=BCa+confidence+interval+efron&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C39&as_sdtp=

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/437477/calculate-accelerated-bootstrap-interval-in-r/437493#437493).